# Is it possible to check if a Mutex is created by using wildcards?

Tags: c#, mutex, wildcard

For example my application creates mutex's like so:

```
MyApplication\\{UserName}
```

and then my updater program (that updates this application) needs to check whether this has been created or not but it doesn't know the username.

I have the code:

```
string mutexString = "MyApplication\\User1"
bool isNew;
var mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexString , out isNew);
if(isNew)
{
   //Run my program
}
```

This works fine if I know the username but I would like to know if it is possible for this to work with wildcards?

Comment: What would you expect to be returned from the wildcard? `new Mutex` creates or retrieves a single instance. What happens if more than one match?

Comment: So I don't need the Mutex object. I just need to know whether the Mutex has already been created or not. Maybe check whether the process is running is a better solution?

Comment: That would be a serious security breach. Anyone could get hold of ALL the mutexes and lock EVERYTHING.

Comment: Its impossible to use wildcards for retrieving mutex.

Comment: Checking if the process is alive sounds like a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So from the comments I get the sense that this is impossible so a better solution might be to check the running processes which I achieved like so:

```
foreach (var process in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (process.MainWindowTitle.IndexOf("MyApp",StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
    {
         isNew = false;
    }   
}
```